# Joomla after migration on localhost

Tags: php, joomla, xampp

I have migrated joomla website from server to my localhost,initially i was not getting the front page content of the website it was just a white screen but the admin panel was working fine and all the contents are present there, then i have changed the error reporting to maximum in the global site configuration inside the admin panel of joomla after this site is showing the following error

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of fancyboxClass::getHeaderLibrary() should be compatible with JAPopupHelper::getHeaderLibrary($bodyString, $identifierString, $headerString) in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\plugins\system\japopup\fancybox\fancybox.php on line 18

Strict Standards: Declaration of oseLanguage::set() should be compatible with JObject::set($property, $value = NULL) in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\administrator\components\com_ose_cpu\oseregistry\oseLanguage.php on line 130

Strict Standards: Declaration of oseMscList::drawTree() should be compatible with oseMscListDraw::drawTree() in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\administrator\components\com_ose_cpu\membership\oseMscListDraw.php on line 365

Strict Standards: Non-static method oseMscConfig::getConfig() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\components\com_osemsc\init.php on line 44

Strict Standards: Static function osePaymentTaxExtend::getTaxAmount() should not be abstract in C:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\administrator\components\com_ose_cpu\payment\osePaymentTax.php on line 135
```

How can i solve these error.
Thanks.

Comment: What is the version of Joomla, php on localhost, php on server?

Comment: Joomla is 2.5, php on localhost 5.4, php on server 5.3.

Comment: Why not just set error reporting to none in your Joomla configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strict standards are quite rife with PHP 5.4. The best thing to do would be to turn strict error reporting off by editing your php.ini file on your localhost and changing this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

to this:

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_STRICT
```

Else simply download the PHP 5.3 extension for your localhost

Hope this helps

Comment: error reporting are already set to error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT maybe i should install 5.3 extention.

Comment: hmm how odd. Did you restart Apache after you changed the *php.ini*?

Comment: Everything is working perfectly now as i have changed the localhost php version to match with the server's version.
Thanks for inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn off strict errors on your local server via `php.ini` or `.htaccess`.

[E_ALL & ~E_STRICT](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting)

Comment: when i turn off them i came back to white screen with no front page contents.